# A question about arc-wise connected Metric spaces.

Tags: general-topology

Let M be a Metric space which is connected, locally connected, and contains more than one point. Do these conditions on M imply that M is always arc-wise connected? I have been unable to find a precise statement-to this effect-in the literature. But I have not been able to cook up any counter-examples.

Comment: For completely metrisable spaces this holds. This is classical, see Engelking 6.3.11. We then have locally arcwise connected (so even stronger) and so arcwise connected as well, from standard arguments.

Answer (score 0):

No. Based on chapter 3-2 of Hocking and Young: There is an example due to R.L. Moore: "A connected and regular point set which contains no arc", Bull. AMS 32, 331-332 (1926), has an example of a subset of the plane which is locally connected, and such that every 2 points lie in a continuum, but which contains no arc. Also, Knaster and Kuratowski ("A connected and connected im kleinen point set which contains no perfect set", Bull. AMS 33, 106-109 (1927)) has a connected and locally connected subset of the plane that contains no continuum at all.

In Hocking and Young they claim the example after theorem 3-6 is such an example as well, without proof.

They also prove the classical theorem that for complete(ly metrisable) such spaces we do have local arcwise connectedness (and thus arc-wise connectedness as well), in theorem 3-17, and the example above show that completeness is essential. Some intuition is presented at the start of chapter 3-2.