# A question about complete metric spaces.

Tags: general-topology

Is there a theorem which states: "Every infinite metric space that is complete, connected and locally connected, is arc-wise connected"?

Comment: According to the [MathWorld article on arc-wise connectedness](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Arcwise-Connected.html),
 "every **locally compact**, connected, locally connected metrizable topological space is arcwise-connected". So if you were willing to trade completeness for local compactness ...

Comment: It's even locally arcwise connected, and thus arc-wise connected as well (as a connected locally arcwise connected space is arcwise connected as well).

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen we can generalise to completely metrisable as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, as I already stated in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1669089/4280). A proof is in Hocking and Young. It's a classical result from the 1920's.

Comment: Many thanks for this information. I found out that it was possible for a metric space to be connected and locally co

Comment: Many thanks for this information. I found out that it was possible for an infinite metric space to be connected and locally connected without containing a single arc. But apparently this was proved only fairly recently.

Comment: @GarabedGulbenkian the references in the linked answer are pretty old already. The positive result for complete spaces is older.