# A question about sigma-compact metric spaces

Tags: general-topology

Are any examples known of infinite metric spaces that are connected, locally connected, and sigma compact but not arc-wise connected?

Comment: Have you checked that the examples in my other answer (all 3 of them) are all non-$\sigma$-compact?

Comment: I mean the answer http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1669089/4280, for reference.

Comment: I have been looking at the Knaster and Kuratowski article. His set X is a subset of the Sierpinski curve and I am having a lot of trouble trying to work out whether X is or is not sigma-compact. I do not have access to a math library and can only read articles which I can download from my computer. I am not sure whether I can get Moore's article this way but I am trying.  I don't see a way of getting hold of the topology book. But I really appreciate all the help you have given me. My own efforts to answer the question were getting nowhere.

Comment: I don't think that K and K's set X is sigma-compact. Let C be any compact subset of X. If S is any non-degenerate connected subset of C and if S* is the closure of S, then S* is closed and uncountable. Hence S* contains a perfect subset and X is not allowed to contain perfect subsets. Consequently C is totally disconnected and therefore zero-dimensional. But if X is sigma-compact, then X is zero-dimensional and so cannot be connected. Contradiction!

Comment: That last argument looks right (using the countable closed sum theorem from dimension theory). That kills one potential counterexample.

Comment: I was able to access the article of R.L, Moore. His set M is a countable union of closed subsets of the Euclidean plane. Since the Euclidean plane is sigma-compact, this makes M sigma-compact. So here is an example of the kind of metric space I have been looking for. Moore does not mention sigma-compactness as a further noteworthy property of his set  M. But maybe sigma-compactness was not of much interest to topologists at that time.

Comment: his observation is equivalent and the term sigma-compact might not even have been coined yet.

Comment: Could you perhaps answer your own question, having found the answer you're looking for? I would like to see a well-explained answer to this myself please!